# How to get the maximum length for a value of populated csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv with two columns "id" and "results". One "id" can appear on csv repeatedly with same or different values. I want to group the csv by each column and calculate the id with the maximum length of "results".

**Input CSV**

```
id, result
Test10001, 400
Test10001, 404
Test10001, 200
Test10002, 404
Test10002, 404 
Test10003, 400
```

I thought of using dataframes and have done upto below so far.

```
grouped_data = data.groupby('id')['result'].apply(list)
```

**output - grouped csv**

```
id
Test10001 [400, 404, 200]
Test10002 [404, 404] 
Test10003 [400]
```

now I want to get the which "id" has the maximum length of list. I am having a trouble to get the length of each, as the type of the  **grouped_data** is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.

Please assist me on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add the desired output

Comment: maximum length of the list of results for a id.

Comment: What would be the desired output if two (or more) IDs had the same length list?

Answer (score 1):

You use use `groupby` in this manner

```
groups=data.groupby('id')['result'].apply(list).reset_index()
groups['Length']=groups['result'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
max_len=groups['Length'].max()
required_df=groups[groups['Length']==max_len]
```

You can use the reset_index() function to get your appropriate results

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of the list in the groupby operation by -

```
grouped = data.groupby('id').agg(length=('result', 'size'))
```

Then you can either use [argmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html) -

```
grouped.iloc[grouped['length'].argmax()]
```

Or get filter by the max length -

```
grouped[grouped['length']==grouped['length'].max()]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this without the aid of a dataframe, it's as simple as...

```
FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/input.csv'

d = {}

_max = 0, None

with open(FILENAME) as csv:
    next(csv) # skip header
    for row in csv:
        k, n = row.split(',')
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(n)
        if (_l := len(d[k])) > _max[0]:
            _max = _l, k

print(_max[1])
```

**Output:**

```
Test10001
```

This assumes that there's only one id that matches the maximum length. If there's more than one then the output may not be as expected.

If there could be more than one id matching the criteria then...

```
FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/input.csv'

d = {}

_max = 0

with open(FILENAME) as csv:
    next(csv) # skip header
    for row in csv:
        k, n = row.split(',')
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(n)
        _max = max(_max, len(d[k]))

print(*[k for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == _max])
```